# Can't compile programs on flash drive

Tags: permissions, compiling, flash, drive

I have mounted my flash drive to a new mount point inside my home folder. However, when I still try to compile my .cpp file, it tells me permission denied. How can I fix this?

1) In GParted, my flash drive is referred to as `/dev/sdc1` . And here, under the Mounte Pointe label, it says the path is `/home/myName/newMount`

2) So when I open my home folder, I see the newMount folder, and inside are all the contents of my flash drive. However, when I try to compile a program, it won't let me. Here are the steps I take:

- `$ cd newMount`
- `$ cd test` (test is the C++ folder containing my program)
- `$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test`
- `$ ./test`

And by running the `mount` command, I am getting this line of text from my flash drive: `/dev/sdc1 on /home/myName/newMount type vfat (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,fmask=0022,dmask=0000)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mounting external hard disk for all users at start up in ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/547965/mounting-external-hard-disk-for-all-users-at-start-up-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i change permissions on a FAT32 formatted drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/96923/how-do-i-change-permissions-on-a-fat32-formatted-drive)

Comment: You don't have execute permissions on the flash drive because FAT doesn't support execute permissions. You will just need to remount the drive. See the link I just put as duplicate.

Comment: Do not [double post](http://askubuntu.com/q/774885/108204). Try [edit]ing this question instead of trying to ask a new one.

Comment: @MattClark Sorry about that, I'm just very desperate to resolve this issue. I have been working on this all day. I edited the question.

Comment: Please [edit] you post again to include the relevant output of `mount`, and then the full output of `ls -alF /home/myName/newMount`, or whatever you mount path is.

Comment: @MattClark ok, I fixed the original post.

Comment: what happen when you compile on your disk instead of flash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some private chat and debugging with the author - It would seem that you have your USB drive mounted with the `noexec` flag - this is preventing you from executing anything off of the drive, even if you have the permission explicitly set.

To fix this, simply `remount` the usb drive with the `exec` flag.

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /home/myName/newMount
```

Using `remount`, all other flags will remain the same.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I've been in a frantic mode trying to resolve this issue. But when I try to do `chmod u+x test` I get a response back saying 
`chmod: changing permissions of ‘test’: Operation not permitted`

Comment: `sudo chmod ...` like stated in my previous comment, please post the output of `ls -alF /path/to/mountPoint`, you may just not be the owner of the USB drive, it may be owned by root.

Comment: I apologize if I sound ignorant, but what is the `ls -alF/path/to/mountPoint` ? And also, when I ran the `sudo chmod...` it still tells me "permission denied". I sincerely apologize if I am causing anger, I am in desperate need to gain access to my flash drive.

Comment: [ls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) -alF (all, list, format) then your mount point, this will show all files in that directory with their owner, and full permission set. It will help us debug.

Comment: `$ ls -alF/home/myName/newMount`
And I get this output:
"ls: invalid option -- '/' "
"Try 'ls --help' for more information. "

Comment: Space between flags and path. Space before the first /

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40027/discussion-between-dhaneku-b-and-matt-clark).

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are trying. I am guessing that your drive is getting mounted automatically but when you are trying to compile a file on your flash drive you get permission denied. Seems like you may have copied files with root privileges. You might want to try `sudo chmod -R a+r /path/to/folder/`, if you also want to store files on the device, also run `sudo chmod -R a+w /path/to/folder/`.

Comment: It's probably formatted in FAT, so chmod is not going to work.